# How to connect to remote Playwright server without creating local driver?

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

Assuming that Playwright server is the solution to [Run Playwright Tests on unsupported Linux distributions](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/26482#issuecomment-1959064576), I want to run my Java test against a Playwright server (which is running using an official Playwright Docker image).

Unfortunately, this doesn't work when the Java test itself is running on an unsupported Linux distribution, because it always wants to create a local driver, for details see [my comment on a feature request for a Playwright.connect() for remote connection](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4687#issuecomment-1959284645)

Is there perhaps a solution to work around this in Java code?

(Asking the same in https://discord.com/channels/807756831384403968/1210218908980617217/1210218908980617217 )